# Is there a SVProgressHUD or KVNProgress kind of library in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mbprogresshud, svprogresshud, kvnprogress

I want to show a similar kind of progress hud as above two but it should be written in Swift only. Can anyone provide some link to similar library?

Comment: Check this one; https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I use SVProgressHUD in my swift apps all the time, no problem. What do you expect to gain from a swift implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created [MKProgress](https://github.com/kamirana4/MKProgress) in `Swift` as one of our `obj-c` app was using `KVNProgress` but it was not maintained/updated for long time so i thought to have a similar one. You can try it. It looks like this

[image][image][image]

Comment: Thanks. It looks fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can find a lot of indicators and other awesome `Swift` libraries [here](https://github.com/vsouza/awesome-ios#activity-indicator).

This is my favorite:

- https://github.com/ninjaprox/NVActivityIndicatorView - there is a whole collection of indicators
- https://github.com/shubh10/JustHUD - and there easy and nice indicator